# How to use CMake with Catch2?

Tags: c++, cmake, catch-unit-test

From [Catch2's example](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#writing-tests), I tried to run this example with `cmake` where structure of my project is like this:

```
/factorial
    +-- CMakeLists.txt
    +-- /bin
    +-- /include
    |     +-- catch.hpp
    |     +-- fact.hpp 
    +-- /src
    |     +-- CMakeLists.txt
    |    +-- fact.cpp
    +-- /test
         +-- CMakeLists.txt
         +-- test_fact.cpp
```

`fact.cpp`:

```
unsigned int factorial( unsigned int number ) {
    return number <= 1 ? number : factorial(number-1)*number;
}
```

`fact.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FACT_H
#define FACT_H

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int);

#endif
```

`test_fact.cpp`:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "fact.hpp"

TEST_CASE( "factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( factorial(2) == 2 );
    REQUIRE( factorial(3) == 6 );
    REQUIRE( factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

I tried several ways already to build this project with `cmake` but it's failed. Sometimes I got an error:

```
cpp:X:XX: fatal error: 'fact.hpp' file not found
...
```

and sometimes I got:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
...
```

when I run `make`.

What should I have in `factorial/CMakeLists.txt`,`factorial/src/CMakeLists.txt` and `factorial/test/CMakeLists.txt`, if I want to have my execution files in `factorial/bin`?

Additional:
This is my CMakeLists.txts (I think they are completely wrong).

`factorial/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(factorial)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_definitions("-std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

`factorial/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(factorial)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_executable(fact fact.cpp)
```

`factorial/test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(factorial)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_executable(test_fact test_fact.cpp)
target_include_directories(test_fact PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

Comment: what is the content of your cmake files?

Comment: Did you check out their minimal example [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/build-systems.md)

Comment: Do your CMake files contain `include_directories(include)` anywhere? (Or at the minimum, a `target_include_directories()`)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I'm writing please wait. Carl not yet thanks.

Comment: For the second problem, you can do: `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)`. However, I would recommend that you do _not_ do this, but rather keep executables in the directories where they were created.

Comment: ok, I added my make files but I think they are totally wrong.

Comment: there is a bug: factorial of 0 expected to be 1, but current implementation will give you 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many problems here:

```
add_executable(fact fact.cpp)
```

The call should be using `add_library` (You could also specify `STATIC` or `SHARED`), since you are only defining a factorial function, not an executable *with a `main` function*.

```
add_executable(fact fact.cpp)
```

The file should be `test_fact.cpp` and the target should have a different name to avoid conflict with the previous library you created. Also, your `fact.cpp` doesn't include `fact.hpp`. Last but not least, instead of doing `target_include_directories`, just write the following in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(include)
```

Now, all subdirectories should be able to access the header files. Beware that this removes control of the scoping of the header files (`PRIVATE` vs `PUBLIC` vs `INTERFACE`) and allows *all* subdirectories to access the header files. If you want to restrict this behavior, then use `target_include_direcories` for all targets (Your library and the test executable). For this example, since everything needs to access the header files, there is no problem with the statement above.

More problems:

```
project(factorial)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
```

Either switch the order of these statements, or remove both of them. (You only need them in your top level CMake file)

Comment: How can you suggest someone to use `include_directories` instead of `target_include_directories` and sleep at night?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot For this example, it isn't really necessary to specify includes on a target by target basis. However, I will add a note saying that `target_include_directories` is the better practice.

Comment: "The call should be using `add_library`" and "The file should be test_fact.cpp" -  `add_library(fact fact.cpp)` and then `add_executable(fact test_fact.cpp)` raises CMake error: "add_executable cannot create target "fact" because another
  target with the same name already exists.". Did I misunderstand the suggestion?

Comment: @swdon You're correct, I didn't realize I specified 2 targets with the same name, they should have been different.

Comment: so what is causing the linking error here? It doesn't seem to be adressed

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the CMake documentation, the `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` variable is define as that:

> Top level source directory for the current project.
>
> This is the source directory of the most recent project() command.

Since you called `project` many times, that variable will constantly change. I would suggest you to remove your project directive,  or to use `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, which always point to the source directory of the whole project.

---

As a side note, I suggest to use `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` instead of `add_definition`