# How to integrate Catch2 as external library with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I am trying to set up a learning project using Catch2 and I decided that it was
best to clone the repository in a Cpp folder, so I could get updates and use it
for other C++ projects. The installing method is as described [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md#installing-catch2-from-git-repository).

The basic folder structure is:

```
Cpp
├───TestProject
│   ├───main.cpp
│   ├───.vscode
│   └───build
│       ├───CMakeFiles
│       └───Testing
└───Catch2
   ├─── ...
  ...
```

As per [Catch2 documentation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md#cmake-target) I put this on my CMake file:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)
```

However, when I try to configure the project in VS Code, I get the following error message:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
[cmake]   Cannot specify link libraries for target "tests" which is not built by this
[cmake]   project.
```

`main.cpp` is just a Hello World file and the complete CMakeLists.txt file contents are:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TestProject VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)
enable_testing()

add_library(TestProject TestProject.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

I am unsure why this happens. I am a complete newcomer to CMake, save for very
basic commands I had to use at work. I guess it would be less work to just drop
it as a header file like it's intended to, but this approach made more sense to
me...

Note: I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413898/how-to-use-cmake-with-catch2). However his question had to do with
Catch2 as a header file inside the project.

Note 2: desired behaviour is to build the project using Catch2 as an external
library.

(Additional information: CMake --version is 3.13.3, using CMakeTools in VS Code,
OS is Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

First, since the library has been installed through CMake (same applies for installs using a package manager), it is recommended to flag `find_package` with `CONFIG` (read about Config mode [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/find_package.html?highlight=i#full-signature-and-config-mode)).
This is because even if Catch2 repository is in a parent, common folder to the project, the CMake installation process installs it in your Program Files folder (in Windows); i.e. the repository is just that.

Additionally you should `add_executable(tests main.cpp)` so CMake has "tests" as a target.
This solves the original problem.

However, for it to completely work, you need to follow these additional steps:

1. Use `catch_discover_tests(tests)`
2. `include(CTest)` possibly necessary.
3. The include preprocessor command should be: `#include <catch2/catch.hpp>` instead of simply `#include "catch.hpp"`.

Also, make sure your editor is aware of the environmental variables created
during the installation of Catch2. That is, if you are having problems, restart
the editor so it re-reads environmental variables.

Full CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(TestProject LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(tests main.cpp) # solution to the original problem
target_link_libraries(tests Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest) # not sure if this is 100% necessary
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
enable_testing()
```

Note: Instead of `add_executable`, we should use `add_library`, although no
tests are recognized in library mode for some reason; however that is beyond the
scope of this question as it lies more in the knowledge of use pf Catch2.

Comment: The *only* issue in the original code was the missing call to `tests` target. Everything else mentioned in this answer has absolutely nothing to do with the original question and is completely unnecessary for getting Catch2 to work with CMake.